# xcode 4.5 ignores some of lines

Tags: ios, xcode

I have sometimes strange problem with XCODE 4.5  . xcode ignores some of my lines or any changes Im adding to project. for instance I want to change the amount of an integer but Xcode use the previous amount (surprisingly that amount was replaced by new amount), or I want NSLog some string, it just skip them and doesn't print them in the outline. 
I have restarted my MAC, but nothing changed!

[image]

Comment: What's being missed exactly?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your targets?

Comment: Are you in Release build?

Comment: as you can see in the above image, Im using OHAttributedLabel in my project in a workspace. so the problem is X-CODE skip those edits only in OHAttributedLabel. but when I do something in my project, after that those lines in OHAttributedLabel will compile and everything works. I don't know why this happens! how should I clean My target? and how to know Im in a release build?

Comment: First try cleaning the "product"  (Product -> Clean).  If that does not work, try deleting derived objects (in Organizer, select Projects, select your project from list on left, the select the top Delete... button.